# Razor Document Formatter Stop Breaking Lines

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

Is there a place to teach the Razor (it could R#, since I have that installed, too) document formatter / pretty-printer some new tricks?  Like not break longish lines, not break tags apart at all, or adding a break before a closing tag, e.g. `</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's part of the options in visual studio. Go to "Tools | Options". I also change "Tag Specific Options..." as well because I like my html formatted a specific way. Razor uses these settings when formatting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir.  In a fit of myopic silliness I was only looking in the R# dialog.